# Breaking down serialized json string into array of jsonObjects for Android

Tags: java, android, json

I have a serialized json string in the format:

```
"[{\"Version\":\"8.63\",\"Date\":\"07\/11\/2011 00:00:00\",\"Count\":213},
{\"Version\":\"1.0\",\"Date\":\"07\/11\/2011 00:00:00\",\"Count\":1},
.........
,{\"Version\":\"7.7\",\"Date\":\"31\/10\/2011 00:00:00\",\"Count\":0}]"
```

I want to break down this string into an array of jsonObjects. I know if you have a string containing only one jsonObject then we can easily create a jsonObject.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a

[new JSONArray(withYourString);](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: when I create a JSONArray with my string it gives me the following error:: WARN/System.err(332): org.json.JSONException: Value [{"Version":"(All)","Date":"07/11/2011 00:00:00","Count":332} WARN/System.err(332): at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107),WARN/System.err(332):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:91)
, so I am unable to convert it into JSONArray

Answer (score 2):

If you really want an array of JSONObjects and not a JSONArray you can do this this way:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(string);
JSONObject[] objects = new JSONObject[array.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    objects[i] = array.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

Comment: I added the brackets on the "objects" array declaration

Comment: it gives me a type mismatch error when I convert it into JSONArray.

Comment: Then you dont have an invalid JSONArray string representation.